# How to anonymize self-citation of source code repository in IEEE double blind peer review?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, code, anonymity

I am  going to submit a paper IEEE Communications letters.

In the paper, I cited my source code repository to provide an open access:

> ... For more detail, please refer [1] ...
>
> - Reference
>
>   1. My real name, My project name "https://my-source-code-repository", Accessed: 2016-02-17.

However, IEEE Communicaitons Letters is doing double blind peer review and information about authors should be blinded. In this situation, how could I make it blinded?

1. Anonymize *project name*
2. Anonymize *repository URL*

   - Reviews might not able to validate the work
3. Anonymize project committer
4. Anonymize everything

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think most reviewers for IEEE Communications Letters are unlikely to visit your source code link and try and validate your code. It's fairly unusual in this field (I say this as someone in the same field.) Certainly the reviewers will not *expect* access to your code. So if you want to anonymize everything, that would be fine.

If you want to preserve the ability of reviewers to access your code (which is a very good thing!) and don't mind going to a little bit of extra trouble, you could always just upload an anonymized tar.gz archive containing the source code (without the version control metadata) to any file sharing site. Then use that URL in the version you submit for review. (When the paper is accepted, you can update the reference to point to your non-anonymous repository.)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of source code, you should provide the executable binary, together with all the scripts to re-produce your experiments. I don't think any reviewer has the patience to read your source code.

In some conference in my field, it is suggested that the authors set up a virtual machine, e.g. a Ubuntu image, and install the compiled tool there.

In order to host these artifacts, you don't need a repository. You only need to put it in, e.g., google drive or dropbox.

Please note that if your repository is in your website, the reviewers will not visit it, for fear of being tracked.

Comment: "Please note that if your repository is in your website, the reviewers will not visit it, for fear of being tracked." Smart, thinking about the double-blind from the reviewers' perspective, also.

Comment: Distributing an executable binary does not allow reviewers to validate the work the way that distributing source code does. Without source code, all I could say is "Yes, this black box does indeed produce the output that the authors claim for the input that the authors specify".. but I can't say whether the inner workings of that box are valid. (I agree that reviewers are not likely to review source code, but if the author is willing to share code, I would *never* recommend to *only* share a binary executable instead!)

Comment: (See [this story for example](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57261/how-to-deal-with-low-quality-software-project-that-needs-to-be-evaluated): "When I look at the part of the project which should process the `general_input_file`, there is a statement which looks like this: if the name of the given input file equals `specific_input_file`, then return `specific_output_file`. This is a file inside the project. Otherwise, try to process the `generate_input_file` and generate `general_output_file`. At this point the software breaks.")

Comment: Just because the executable binary works on one computer doesn't mean that it will work on another computer (say, the reviewer's computer), which could be a completely different architecture.

Comment: Would a typical reviewer really be so lax about their security as to run random executable binaries? (I am afraid the answer is yes, but I'm still shocked at the suggestion of distributing executable binaries to someone who doesn't know your identity and has no good reason to trust you.)

Comment: @Joshua, ShreevatsaR: yes, that's why I said it is recommended to run on a virtual machine, which you can do all the setup.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is good to add your source code reference to your manuscript, I don't suppose citing it in its full form is encouraged as per the [double-review guidelines of IEEE Communication Letters](http://www.comsoc.org/cl/author-guidelines). One alternative would be to store it in a temporary cloud location as @ff524 suggested and then cite it anonymously (with Author1, 2... as in the guidelines). Once accepted, you may relocate it to a proper location with appropriate citation in the paper to be published.

Having said the above, this question is better asked to the publisher for a better clarification.